# How to reach axios requests made from one request

Tags: node.js, axios, request, puppeteer

I am dealing with a request that when called in a browser, will call multiple requests, I managed to capture these requests using puppeteer, but I don't know how to do it in Axios.

for example, make a GET request using Axios to "www.example.com/welcome", this will call about 10 requests inside that request.
in puppeteer, I can do the following to solve this issue:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', async request => {
    const auth = request.headers().authorization;
    if (auth) {
      TOKEN = auth ? auth.substring(6, auth.length) : TOKEN;
      await request.abort();
    } else {

      await request.continue();
    }
  });
```

is there a way to intercept these requests and capture the headers of each of them?

Comment: Axios doesn't do anything other than retrieve the single response (the page's static HTML in this case) as plain text. You need Puppeteer if you want to run the page and intercept other requests that the JS code on that initial static page makes. All you could do with Axios is get the raw HTML string, then use a parser to find links in the string to other endpoints and build the requests yourself, which works in certain circumstances. Without the page you're working with, I can't help further than this broad suggestion.

Comment: Here is the link.
[link](https://www.xe.com/)